# Gradle GradleBuild tasks not run in parallel

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have these tasks in a multi-project build:

```
task runA(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = [
         ':a:x:bootRun',
         ':a:y:bootRun',
         ':c:x:bootRun'
    ]
}

task runB(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = [
         ':b:x:bootRun',
         ':b:y:bootRun',
         ':c:x:bootRun'
    ]
}
```

Each `:a:x` etc. is a separate project (`build.gradle` / `build.gradle.kts` file). When I invoke `gradle runA` or `gradle runB` all of the subtasks are run in parallel just as they should.

However, when I run `gradle runA runB` only some of the tasks get invoked 
 while I want all five unique tasks `a:x a:y c:x b:x b:y` to be run in parallel.  I have also tried using `dependsOn` instead of the `GradleBuild` task type but that leads to the same outcome (usually only 4 of 5 expected tasks run in parallel).

Note that the tasks never "complete" as they run an application, I'm more or less abusing gradle as a launcher of sorts here. I assume gradle blocks and waits for one of the tasks to complete but there are no dependencies between them.

What do I need to do to force gradle to run all of the tasks in parallel at the same time?

Comment: I don't experience what you said. Doing `gradle runA` does not run all the tasks in parallel. I actually have to do `gradle --parallel runA` for that to work

Answer (score 0):

Gradle will use heuristics to decide how many things to run in parallel. So the most likely explanation is that by default it is limiting itself to 4 parallel tasks.

You can [control this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) via `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.workers.max=(max # of worker processes)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've checked this (12 on my machine is the default, setting it explicitly didn't help either). The funny thing is that a `runX` task with all  5 tasks listed directly works as it should...